# Store object reference in DataGridView row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a method as such :

```
public void setResults(Documents[] doc)
{

    //I call a method to set the columns 
    setColumns(doc[0].getColumnsToDisplay())

    //Here i populate the DataGrid

   foreach (Documents element in doc)
   {
                     /dt is a datatable
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        foreach (string col in results[0].getColumnsToDisplay())
        {
          object val;
          (element.getAttributes() as IDictionary<string, object>).TryGetValue(col, out val);
           dr[col] = val.ToString();    
        }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    }
       gridSearchResults.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

Is there a way to store "doc" reference on each row ? so that if i select a row, i can be able to return the "doc" object ? Looking for some kind of `Tag` property alternative for rows or something different.

Comment: If you set your array as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` you can access to the underlying object of each row using `DataBoundItem` property of `DataGridViewRow`. Is this what you need?

Comment: I've provided an answer for this question that deserved to have an accepted answer to be more useful for future readers. Let me know your idea about the answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to show a list of your objects in a `DataGridView`, you don't need to use a `DataTable`. You can simply set your list as `DataSource` of your `DataGridView`:

```
public void setResults(Documents[] doc)
{
    gridSearchResults.DataSource = doc;
}
```

Then if you want to know the object behind the row, you can simply use [`DataBoundItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `DataGridViewRow` and cast it to your object type:

```
var documents= (Documents)gridSearchResults.Rows[0].DataBoundItem;
```

For more information and samples, you can see:

- [How to: Access Objects Bound to Windows Forms DataGridView Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wszzzc7(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want to show only some columns in the `DataGridView`, add the columns you need this way:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

//Create Column
var column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    Name = "firstNameColumn",        /*Name of Column*/
    HeaderText = "First Name",       /*Title of Column*/
    DataPropertyName = "FirstName"   /*Name of the property to bind to cilumn*/
};

//Add column to grid
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Reza, sorry for the reluctant reply since i found a different approach by using Listview with combobox which works nicely. My plan was just to display the results on a table and let the user pick one. Thank you once again it will help future seekers.

Comment: You are welcome, and thank you for your kind feedback :) I personally try to avoid solutions based on `ListView` and try to use `DataGridView` when possible, because it supports `DataBinding` and is very customizable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use DataGridView instead of DataGrid. I assume you're trying to get the object after postback.

```
//DO NECESSARY NULL CHECKS!!!
DataRow row = (gridSearchResults.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as  DataRowView).Row;
Documents selected = (Documents)row;
```

Comment: It was datagridview, sorry for the misinformation. I tried that approach and casted but it failed to cast object. This is because document object is a complex type: certain mandatory attributes which are not visible on the table.

Comment: You should add Documents object as datarow not it's value. 

       dr[col] =element; // Where element is Documents object.

Check this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2007/01/19/how-to-bind-a-datagridview-column-to-a-second-level-property-of-a-data-source.aspx